# Editing notification messages in joomla

Tags: joomla, notifications

How do I increase the display time of on-screen notifications in joomla? E.g when a user registers. What file do I edit to achieve this?
The same question was also asked here:
https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=890658

Comment: It would depend on what template you use. What is your template name?

Comment: @webchun my template is called in Style. By Gavick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved this by editing the following line on the default.php page in the layout of the template:

```
<?php if(count($app->getMessageQueue())) : ?>
           <jdoc:include type="message" />
           <?php endif; ?>
```

The above line neds to be changed to just `<jdoc:include type="message" />` to ensure the system messages/notification stay permanently on the screen.